# Sorting the view based on frequency in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a `StockinHand` view generated from `stock_Outward` & `Stock_Inward` tables right now needs the sorting based on frequency i.e most moving stock items should be on top of the table

My tables are like below:

`tbl_StockInward`:

```
ID, Stock_Code,Units,Rate, Description, Vendor, DateOfPurchase, DateOfUpdate, Purchased_By, WareHouse, Remarks,
```

vice versa `tbl_StockOutward`

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in sub queries, you can't use `ORDER BY` in a view definition in sql server unless you also use `TOP`.

The reason for this is that Views are acted upon as if they where tables, and tables in sql server (in fact, in any relational database) are considered as not ordered sets.
Just like there is no meaning to the order of records stored in a table, there is also no meaning to the order of records fetched by a view.
You can use a dirty hack and write `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ...` and then use `ORDER BY`, but I doubt if it has any meaning at all.

**H**aving said all that, you can of course use `ORDER BY` in any query that selects from a view.

Comment: As far as I know, `SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ...... ORDER BY` works, but not always. It's better and recommended to sort view when you're querying it. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: It works, but it's meaningless since rows in a view are considered unorderd. this is the hole point of my answer.