# Can I use inner select that uses FOR xml Path inside a view

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, view

SQL Server 2008 R2: can I use an inner select that uses `FOR XML PATH` inside a view? The purpose of 'relatedProductIDString' is to produce a comma delimited string of IDs in one field.

Here is the inner select

```
(SELECT 
     CAST(productRelated.relatedProductID AS varchar) + ', '
 FROM 
     productRelated
 WHERE 
     productRelated.parentProductId = productWebSource.ProductWebID 
 FOR XML PATH('')) AS relatedProductIDString
```

Note, it does work when you run it. It allows me to save the view and query the view. But when I open it  in design view three weird things happen:

1. I get an error in `where` clause near '(' - Error in order by clause. Unable to pass query text
2. the first section is missing, there are no tables in the diagram area
3. the second section is missing, there are no fields in the filed list.

This said, click OK to the error described at 1, run my view and the correct results are showing.

Here is the full view for completeness:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.productWebSource.ProductWebID AS productID, 
    dbo.productWebSource.ProductName AS productName, 
    dbo.ProductType.ProductTypeName AS productType, 
    dbo.ProductStatus.ProductStatusDesc AS productStatus, 
    dbo.productWebSource.metaData, 
    dbo.productWebSource.metaDescription, 
    dbo.productWebSource.classification, 
    dbo.productWebSource.trademarkName, 
    dbo.trademarkOwner.title AS trademarkOwnerName, 
    dbo.productWebSource.RegCountry AS country, 
    dbo.productWebSource.vetExclusive, 
    dbo.productWebSource.ProductDesc AS basicDescription, 
    dbo.productWebSource.UVPNumber AS uvpNumber,
    (SELECT CAST(productRelated.relatedProductID AS varchar) + ', '
     FROM productRelated
     WHERE productRelated.parentProductId = productWebSource.ProductWebID FOR XML PATH('')) AS relatedProductIDString
FROM  
    dbo.ProductType 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.productWebSource ON dbo.ProductType.ProductTypeID = dbo.productWebSource.ProductTypeID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.ProductStatus ON dbo.productWebSource.ProductStatusID = dbo.ProductStatus.ProductStatusID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.trademarkOwner ON dbo.productWebSource.trademarkOwnerId = dbo.trademarkOwner.trademarkOwnerId
WHERE 
    (dbo.productWebSource.ProductStatusID < 4)
ORDER BY 
    productName
```

Very weird. It appears to work, can be queried but does not behave in design view and has this error every time I open the view (in design view).  Have I done something that works but is not supposed to?

Comment: Not an answer but [using order by in views is useless.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045871/sorting-the-view-based-on-frequency-in-sql-server/30046050#30046050)

Comment: The query designer has limited capabilities. I think you should get used to write your queries directly (without the designer). They will be shorter (using aliases), more readable, and (most importantly) you will be able to use features that are unavailable in the designer (subqueries, cross apply, etc).

Comment: About the order by, wow I did not know this.   Of course it does obey the order by when you are building the view but after researching this I am now aware this is 'useless'  thanks for pointing this out.   I have never liked views to be honest.  I hardley ever use them, in this case I have been asked to use them...

Comment: About 'designers limited capabilities'   As I touched on in the message above I am not a fan of views at all.   In this situation I have been asked to specifically create a bunch of views.  So getting back to my original question and the point of this post, am I allowed to use FOR XML PATH in a view?   FYI otherwise I alwasy write my own queries and agree with all your points

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to use FOR XML PATH in a view. However, I recommend you create your views using the CREATE VIEW statement in a Query Window, not using the View Designer.